# Dymola simulateMultiResultsModel function kills seemingly random instances

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to run a series of parametric simulations by varying a parameter `lesThrTOut.threshold` in my model (a `Modelica.Blocks.Logical.LessThreshold` block). I have been trying to get the function `simulateMultiResultsModel` to run multiple simulations at once across a number of cores, however, when I execute the following command

```
simulateMultiResultsModel(
    "Thesis_Project.Experiments.HHSElecGasUsageCalib",
    stopTime=604800,
    method="Radau",
    tolerance=1e-06,
    numberOfIntervals=500,
    resultFile="HHSElecGasUsageCalib",
    initialNames={"lesThrTOut.threshold"},
    initialValues=[3:1:9]);
```

Dymola simply says "Failed" along the bottom (next to the logs button), and what seems to be a random number of dymosim.exe terminals crash without logs as to why they crashed, and the remaining instances continue their simulations. As you can tell from my function call, I am trying to simulate 7 versions of the model. I have gotten as many as 5 to complete simulation, and other times it has been only a single instance which didn't fail. Does anyone have any insight as you why this may be occurring? No logs are returned so I cannot tell *why* these instances are failing.

I have tried different initial value set ups, I have tried it on different model parameters, I have tried changing the block's `threshold` value to be based off of a `parameter Real foo=3` and then perturbing `foo` in the `simulateMultiResultsModel` call.

Edit: I'm using the simulateMultiResultsModel because it uses more than a single core. The parameter sweep tool in Dymola is supposed to run multi-core but it doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: Have you tried running a "standard simulation" with the value for `lesThrTOut.threshold` that make `simulateMultiResultsModel` fail? To my experience, models often fail for a certain (set of) parameters. This way you would get the standard outputs/logs making debugging easier...

Comment: When using the regular `simulateModel` command, the simulation never fails for any value of `lesThrTOut.threshold`, that's what's so weird. In more recent attempts to get this working, only ever one or two instances make it past initialisation. I thought then that it was a RAM issue or something but my system still has multiple GBs left so I don't think that's the issue. There are various settings in Dymola for log reporting, but none of them seem to post logs for failed `simulateMultiResultsModel` instances.

Comment: To narrow the problem down you could try to run multiple simulations with the same values, e.g. using `initialValues=fill(3, 100, 1)`.

Comment: Regarding "The parameter sweep tool in Dymola is supposed to run multi-core but it doesn't seem to for me.": The use of parallel simulations on multi-core setups was introduced with Dymola 2020. I assume you have a newer version? Also check the value of `Advanced.NumberOfCores`, it should either be zero (=use all cores) or the number of cores you want to use...

Comment: @MarkusA. I have `Advanced.NumberOfCores` set to zero, and yes, I'm running Dymola 2022. When I execute sweep parameter, very strange behaviour occurs: it runs the simulations one by one sequentially, and uses core 1 for about ten seconds before moving on to core 2 for ten seconds etc... One thing I forgot to mention is, when I execute `simulateMultiResultsModel` all of the terminals say "Files opened" when they first appear, and then die off one by one. @marco I tried `initialValues=fill(3, 100, 1)` but changed 100 to 5 to not fry my PC, same thing happened, random ones killed.

Comment: Could it be my license? I'm using the Academic Learn License provided by Claytex through my university.

Comment: It shouldn't be the academic license.

Comment: Another idea is that the "Max run time" is set in "Simulation Setup" -> "General". This could kill some, but not all simulations depending on the performance - not very likely but possible...

Comment: @MarkusA. I don't understand. What should the max run time be? It is set the same as the function call, 604800

Comment: It is the maximum wall-clock-time the model is allowed to run. After this amount of time is spent on the simulation, the executable is stopped. By default it should be inactive, but you can check the variable `Advanced.Simulation.MaxRunTime` to get its value (0.0 means inactive).